# unable to open my href in an ul when clicking on them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I read a lot of similar questions but I'm still un able to find a solution, even if I think I know what the problem may be. I think one of my div is overlaying the links but I can't find which one or how to change it.
I would really apreciate any kind of help.

my html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>Implant cochléaire-Projet TAL</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./img/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="./css/slimmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!--web-fonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--web-fonts-->

<script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--div class="wrap"-->
            <div class="header">
                <header id="topnav">
                    <nav>
                         <ul>

                            <li class="active" class="scroll"><a href="index.html">Accueil</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/presentation.html">Pr&eacute;sentation</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/resultats.html">R&eacute;sultats</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/nuage.html">Nuage</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="https://projetplurital.wordpress.com/">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/liens.html">Liens</a></li>                             
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                 <h1><a><img src="" alt=""></a></h1>
                    <a href="#" id="navbtn">Nav Menu</a>
                </header>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        <!--/div-->
    <!-----script------------->
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="./js/menu.js"></script>

<div class="slider" id="accueil">
```

and the css

```
/* start header */

::selection { background: #b9e9b9; color: #555; }
::-moz-selection { background: #b9e9b9; color: #555; }
::-webkit-selection { background: #b9e9b9; color: #555; }

br { display: block; line-height: 2.2em; } 

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

#tablo{

position:absolute;
left:50%;
width:760px;
margin-left:-380px;


    }
#w {
 max-width:70%%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
 margin: 0 0em;
 background: #fff;
}

#pagebody {
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

/* navigation bar */
#topnav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

#topnav h1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 2.2em 0em;
}
#topnav h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1px 7px;
    display: block;
color: #000000;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-weight:400;
}

#topnav #navbtn {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  padding: 2.5em 0em;
  background: url('../images/menu-icon.png') center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#topnav nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: -10px;
  padding: 2.9em 0em;
}

#topnav nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#topnav nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin:0em 0.5em;
}

#topnav nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
#topnav nav ul li a:hover {
  color:#E47065;
}
#topnav nav ul li.active>a {
  color:#E47065;
}
/* footer block */
#btmnav {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#btmnav .credits { 
  color: #999;
  line-height: 1.45em;
}
#btmnav nav { padding: 9px 0; padding-bottom: 15px; }
#btmnav nav ul li { display: inline; }
#btmnav nav ul li a { font-weight: bold; }


/* responsive styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  h2 { font-size: 2.2em; }
  p { font-size: 1.45em; line-height: 1.55em; }
  #topnav h1 {
    padding: 1.4em 0em;
    }
    #topnav #navbtn {
    padding:0.5em 0em;
    }
  #topnav { height: auto; }
  #topnav nav { 
    display: none; 
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  #topnav nav ul li { float: none; margin: 0;  background: #f0f0f0;}
  #topnav nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height:1.9em;
    border: 0;
    border-radius:0px;
    padding: 9px 9px;
    color:#303030;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(90, 85, 73, 0.17);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background: none;
   }
  #topnav nav ul li a.sel {
    color: #6f8767;
   background: #cbdcc5;
  }

  #topnav #navbtn {
    display: block;
    padding: 2em 0;
  }
}
/*---End-top-header----*/
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue? Preferably as a snippet here in the question. I put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1onjvyfh/2/), but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

```
<a href="./fr/presentation.html">
```

and similar.

If you want to navigate to the parent directory (which I assume), you need two dots in the beginning:

```
<a href="../fr/presentation.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave your JavaScript code only a link, I put the code (without the JS) on jsfiddle and without the JavaScript there is no problem so most likely the problem is somewhere in the JavaScript part. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/g53tv1r6/  What does `<script type="text/javascript"  src="./js/menu.js"></script>`?

Answer (score 0):

take out

```
display: none;
```

from your css selector `#topnav nav`

```css
/* start header */

::selection { background: #b9e9b9; color: #555; }
::-moz-selection { background: #b9e9b9; color: #555; }
::-webkit-selection { background: #b9e9b9; color: #555; }

br { display: block; line-height: 2.2em; } 

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

#tablo{

position:absolute;
left:50%;
width:760px;
margin-left:-380px;


    }
#w {
 max-width:70%%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
 margin: 0 0em;
 background: #fff;
}

#pagebody {
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

/* navigation bar */
#topnav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

#topnav h1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 2.2em 0em;
}
#topnav h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1px 7px;
    display: block;
color: #000000;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-weight:400;
}

#topnav #navbtn {
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  padding: 2.5em 0em;
  background: url('../images/menu-icon.png') center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#topnav nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: -10px;
  padding: 2.9em 0em;
}

#topnav nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#topnav nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin:0em 0.5em;
}

#topnav nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
#topnav nav ul li a:hover {
  color:#E47065;
}
#topnav nav ul li.active>a {
  color:#E47065;
}
/* footer block */
#btmnav {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#btmnav .credits { 
  color: #999;
  line-height: 1.45em;
}
#btmnav nav { padding: 9px 0; padding-bottom: 15px; }
#btmnav nav ul li { display: inline; }
#btmnav nav ul li a { font-weight: bold; }


/* responsive styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  h2 { font-size: 2.2em; }
  p { font-size: 1.45em; line-height: 1.55em; }
  #topnav h1 {
    padding: 1.4em 0em;
    }
    #topnav #navbtn {
    padding:0.5em 0em;
    }
  #topnav { height: auto; }
  #topnav nav { 
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  #topnav nav ul li { float: none; margin: 0;  background: #f0f0f0;}
  #topnav nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height:1.9em;
    border: 0;
    border-radius:0px;
    padding: 9px 9px;
    color:#303030;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(90, 85, 73, 0.17);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background: none;
   }
  #topnav nav ul li a.sel {
    color: #6f8767;
   background: #cbdcc5;
  }

  #topnav #navbtn {
    display: block;
    padding: 2em 0;
  }
}
/*---End-top-header----*/
```

```html
    <title>Implant cochléaire-Projet TAL</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./img/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="./css/slimmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!--web-fonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--web-fonts-->

<script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--div class="wrap"-->
            <div class="header">
                <header id="topnav">
                    <nav>
                         <ul>

                            <li class="active" class="scroll"><a href="index.html">Accueil</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/presentation.html">Pr&eacute;sentation</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/resultats.html">R&eacute;sultats</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/nuage.html">Nuage</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="https://projetplurital.wordpress.com/">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="./fr/liens.html">Liens</a></li>                             
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                 <h1><a><img src="" alt=""></a></h1>
                    <a href="#" id="navbtn">Nav Menu</a>
                </header>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        <!--/div-->
    <!-----script------------->
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="./js/menu.js"></script>

<div class="slider" id="accueil">
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are trying to make it responsive, please try removing `display: none;` from

```
#topnav nav{

}
```

Check the output. Its working now. If you still want more help please expalin the problem in detail.

Check this link for details.

http://jsbin.com/pahujayere/edit?html,css,output